# Using plugins in Uno Css

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, unocss

I am using [unocss](https://unocss.antfu.me/), instead of tailwindcss in a nuxtjs 2 project. I then want to use a few plugins like the [flowbite plugin](https://flowbite.com/) for tailwindcss. How do I make this to work with unocss?

Comment: Not sure of the plus value of using a tailwind plugin since you can have those as Vue components. And also, since the plugin is aimed for Tailwind (UnoCSS is something totally different at the end), I doubt there is a way to use it there. You can always ask it in the discussions: https://github.com/unocss/unocss/discussions

Comment: I went through a blog and discovered that I could just use some presets of unocss (not all of them) and then use either windicss or tailwindcss to load my desired plugins.

Comment: WindiCSS is done by antfu too, and will probably include UnoCSS in the next major version so yeah, kinda logic that this may work.

Comment: UnoCss it's basically an engine for css that is inspired by tailwind and generates the same utilities via presets, it's very different and incompatible with current plugins.